# Should I install MariaDB to my git repo, or locally / individually to all development computers?

Tags: mysql, git, mariadb

I am starting work on a website that will use MariaDB for storing information  (no sensitive information), and would like to keep everything in my git repo.

Originally, I planned on installing MariaDB to the separate computers that I plan to develop on (my desktop and laptop), but decided that it may be easier to store all of MariaDB (the program and the databases) in the git repo, so that one would just need to clone the repo and run MariaDB from the repo just like they would run Node, but I have not found any information on how to do this.

My questions are (1) should I install MariaDB and its databases to my git repo, instead of installing MariaDB in `/usr`, and the database in `/var/lib/mysql`, and (2) how would one do that?

Comment: Wait, what? MariaDB is huge. Use docker.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to put a mariadb runtime environment inside your version control, consider using docker to *describe how* to configure an appropriate mariaDB installation.  I use makefiles atop that to contain the commands I use to build and run the docker but you coould just as easily use a shell script.  Finally, provide a dataabase load script that loads your test database from a text file within the repo.

using docker to describe runtime environments for your application *and* dependencies is awesome.  It strikes a great balance between having an incomplete git repo, and having to put binaries and database data in your version control.  You wouldn't want to track changes to the underlying maria db files, anyway, so best not to commit them.  You can build the docker containers you need on every workstation you use without much trouble, your automation around creating them provides a mechanism to ensure consistency, and by loading a database with the correct test data every time you develop your app, you'll have a better development process and less schema and data related changes.  It works great, I do nothing but docker driven development these days.